# HtmlAgilityPack treats everything after < (less than sign) as attributes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have some input I get via a textarea and I convert that input into a html document, that is later parsed into a PDF document.

When my users input the less than sign (<) everything brakes in my HtmlDocument. HtmlAgilityPack suddenly handles everything after the less than sign as an attribute. See the output:

> Within this Character Data block I can use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &,="" ',="" and="" ')="" *and="" *="" %="" myparamentity;="" will="" be="" expanded="" to="" the="" text="" 'has="" been="" expanded'...however,="" i="" can't="" use="" the="" cend="" sequence(if="" i="" need="" to="" use="" it="" i="" must="" escape="" one="" of="" the="" brackets="" or="" the="" greater-than="" sign).="">

It gets a little better if I just add the

```
htmlDocument.OptionOutputOptimizeAttributeValues = true;
```

which gives me:

> Within this Character Data block I can use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &,= ',= and= ')= *and= *= %= myparamentity;= will= be= expanded= to= the= text= 'has= been= expanded'...however,= i= can't= use= the= cend= sequence(if= i= need= to= use= it= i= must= escape= one= of= the= brackets= or= the= greater-than= sign).=>

I have tried all of the options on the htmldocument and none of them lets me specify that the parser should not be strict. On the other hand I might be able to live with it stripping away the <, but adding all the equal signs doesn't really work for me.

```
void Main()
{
    var input = @"Within this Character Data block I can use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &, ', and ') *and * % MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text 'Has been expanded'...however, I can't use the CEND sequence(if I need to use it I must escape one of the brackets or the greater-than sign).";

    var htmlDoc = WrapContentInHtml(input);

    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml.ToString().Dump();
}

private HtmlDocument WrapContentInHtml(string content)
{
    var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<html>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<head>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<title></title>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</head>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("<body><div id='sagsfremstillingContainer'>");
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine(content); 
    htmlBuilder.AppendLine("</div></body></html>");

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.OptionOutputOptimizeAttributeValues = true;
    var htmlDoc = htmlBuilder.ToString();

    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlDoc);

    return htmlDocument;
}
```

Does anybody have an idea to how I can solve this problem.

The closest question I can find is this:
[Losing the 'less than' sign in HtmlAgilityPack loadhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421527/losing-the-less-than-sign-in-htmlagilitypack-loadhtml)

Where he actually complains about the < disappearing which would be fine for me. Of course fixing the parsing error is the best solution.

EDIT:
I am using HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.9

Comment: HTML-Escape your content. If it containts markup characters it is sure to break.

Comment: That does not only break HtmlAgilityPack I guess. Try looking at it in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content is blatantly wrong. This is not about "strictness", it's really about the fact that you're pretending a piece of text is valid HTML. In fact, the results you are getting are exactly because the parser is *not* strict.

When you need to insert plain text into HTML, you need to encode it first, so that all the various HTML control characters are converted to HTML properly - for example, `<` must be changed to `&lt;` and `&` to `&amp;`.

One way to handle this is to use the DOM - use `InnerText` on the target `div`, instead of slapping strings together and pretending they're HTML. Another is to use some explicit encoding method - for example `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.

Comment: You are right. My problem was that I had already tried to encode the html and the engine I create PDFs with didn't decode them, but I can of course do that myself and then it worked. On another node I was not able to use the InnerText since it is read only and creating a new node from the input above didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) which works even without a reference to `System.Web.dll` which also has [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var input = @"Within this Character Data block I can use double dashes as much as I want (along with <, &, ', and ') *and * % MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text 'Has been expanded'...however, I can't use the CEND sequence(if I need to use it I must escape one of the brackets or the greater-than sign).";
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(input));
Debug.Assert(!htmlDocument.ParseErrors.Any());
```

Result:

```
Within this Character Data block I can use double dashes as much as I want (along with &lt;, &amp;, &#39;, and &#39;) *and * % MyParamEntity; will be expanded to the text &#39;Has been expanded&#39;...however, I can&#39;t use the CEND sequence(if I need to use it I must escape one of the brackets or the greater-than sign).
```